# jQuery UI not working correctly in ASP.NET context

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface

jQuery UI function calls work and do not work, depending on where I call them from on the same page.

I cannot seem to be able to call jQuery UI methods from inside any js functions. I can call them just fine in the  body but not inside a js function. Example: http://pastebin.com/BNByP309 , you can see the two js examples at the bottom that don't work.

I checked and firebug tells me that the jQuery and jQuery UI are actually "loaded" but when I do jquery.ui check inside any js function it says that it's not present. jQuery is.

And obviously, I need to be able to call jQuery ui functions from all the places in js, heh.

Any possible ideas what could be throwing it off completely?
Is it the ASP.NET? ScriptManager? I only use the ScriptManager for easier webservice calls really.

Comment: does it make any difference, if you move your javascript up into you head placeholder? Also, could you submit the generated html source?

Comment: do you have try to use jQuery conflict to see if the '$' is conflict ?

Comment: A-HA! Found the answer.
Don't know why it wasn't obvious, but a user incorporated jQuery incorrectly into one of our components -> I included mine into current master layout -> jquery was included twice -> BOOM


And yes, I'm beating myself with a whip and chain for not realizing this before.

Comment: So it was all solved by reworking the component done by the other developer, extracting the jquery out of his component and placing it in common place and well.. it all plays happy now. Jesus, these problems at times just baffle me to no end :) 

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Double entries of jQuery. User component did a secret include of jQuery and master page also included jQuery, resulted in mad black magic and non-working components.

Thanks!